# What exact syntax do I need in my conmgr file to have an excel connection manager in SSIS use a variable to connect to a file?

Tags: ssis

There are lots of "answers" on the internet about how to use a variable to setup your connection, but all of them are either non-specific, or they simply don't work.

First off, I have no idea how to access the excel connection string other than by directly editing the .conmgr file and changing the connection string there. I've tried clicking everywhere I can think of and I can't find any connectionstring property anywhere in the UI.

Having said that, here is my exact .conmgr file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTS:ConnectionManager xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
  DTS:ObjectName="Excel File Connection Manager"
  DTS:DTSID="{F691B77B-6B45-448D-95C2-86067C254528}"
  DTS:CreationName="EXCEL">
  <DTS:ObjectData>
    <DTS:ConnectionManager
      DTS:ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @[User::FilePath] + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES\" />
  </DTS:ObjectData>
</DTS:ConnectionManager>
```

I've tried 50 different permutations of back slashes and forward slashes as escape characters, pluses inside the quotes, pluses outside the quotes, using quot; instead of the actual quote symbol, etc, etc. I cannot figure out what syntax it's expecting or how it's parsing this. Currently, it's telling me that the name can't begin with the + character.

Does anybody have the exact, specific syntax that would make this specific connection string work?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Expression for the ConnectionString on the Connection Manager to

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @[User::FilePath] + 
";Extended Properties=\"EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES\";"
```

The file should exist though, else you should set DelayValidation to true (also for the DataFlow)

Another way is to set the Expression for ExcelFilePath on the ConnectionManager to your file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll set an Expression on the ExcelFilePath property on the Excel Connection Manager to your variable.

Example:

1. Define your variable, example here is just called "ExcelFilePath"

   [image]
2. Then right click on the Excel Connection Manager and click on properties

   [image]
3. That will open the Properties pane for that connection, usually to the right, click on the "..." next to expressions

   [image]
4. Under property select "ExcelFilePath"

   [image]
5. Then you can either just type in your variable or click on the "..." under expressions and build it that way and click OK

   [image]
6. Click OK on each screen until you're back to properties.   You'll now see that the property is set to the variable.  With the excel connection managers that ExcelFilePath property is used as part of the connection string

   [image]